# Empty array in GET .json with `where`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, where-clause

I'm trying to GET the *first* where `active=1` and return a json.

```
# GET /banners.json
def index
  @banners = Banner.where(active: '1').first
end
```

This is returning an empty array `[]`.
If I change and do `Banner.All` return all the datas correctly

Answer (score 2):

This has more to do with data than with code. Obviously, you do not have any banner where `active` is equal to `1`. If it had, Rails is honest enough to return it for you.

Better than this, you can create scope in `Banner` model like this:

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: 1) }
```

And in your controller, you can call it like following:

```
def index
  @banners = Banner.active.first
end
```